# Do distinct infinities exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

We all know that there are the infinite sets $Q$ and $R$. I have been taught, and also read that there is one to one correspondence between the elements of both sets, and thus both are regarded as equivalent.

But not long ago, I read something new for me from Tom Crilly's *'50 Mathematical Ideas You Really Need to Know'* page 104. Here is what it says word by word:

> Although both sets are infinite, the set $R$ has a higher order of infinity than $Q$.Mathematicians denote $card(Q)$ by) $\aleph _0$, the Hebrew ‘aleph nought’ and $card(R) = c$. So this means $\aleph _0 < c.$

Doesn't this contradict the earlier statement I stated ?

Comment: What you have been taught is wrong. There is no one-to-one correspondence between the set of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ and the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$.

Comment: _Where_  did you read that there is such a correspondence?

Comment: If you haven't seen the proof that there are more reals than rationals yet, then you are now mathematically obliged to learn about [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: While you're at it, make sure you also know that the natural numbers $\mathbb N$, the [integers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_are_Countably_Infinite) $\mathbb Z$ and the [rational numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite) $\mathbb Q$ do have the same cardinality.

Comment: What you've been taught, or read, is absolutely wrong (and Crilly is right). What is true - and you might be misremembering this - is that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\color{red}{\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, we have $|\mathbb{R}| > |\mathbb{Q}|$.

For your main question, I suggest you to check [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), which states that for any set $X$, cardinality of power set $P(X)$ of $X$ is larger than cardinality of $X$, which is
$$|P(X)| > |X|$$
This means, if you give me $\mathbb{R}$, $|P(\mathbb{R})|$ is a distinct infinity from $|\mathbb{R}|$ and $|\mathbb{Q}|$. And you can extend this result even more with $P(P(\mathbb{R}))$ for instance.